# when i use the exec RestApi, i got the error message "x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not xx.xx.xx.xx"

Tags: kubernetes

first i test with https but get 400:upgrade response

then i test with websocket, and get "Can't connect to console: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not xx.xx.xx.xx" when i use NewClient() or Dialer.Dial(url,req.Header) to create the client conn

is it sth related to the Bearer token?

i put it in the request's header

```
wsurl := "wss://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/r/projects/1a92/kubernetes:6443/api/v1/namespaces/NM/pods/testPod-546cdd8d79-7h8nv/exec?command=ls&container=testPod&stderr=true&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=false"

u, err := neturl.Parse(wsurl)

rawConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", u.Host)

wsHeaders := http.Header{
        "Authorization":                   {"Bearer "+env_bearer_token},
        "Origin":                   {"https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/r/projects/1a92/kubernetes:6443"},
        "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions": {"permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame"},

    }

wsConn, resp, err := websocket.NewClient(rawConn, u, wsHeaders, 1024, 1024)
```

anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> is it sth related to the Bearer token?

No, is related to exactly what the error says: the X.509 certificate does not have an `SAN` entry for whatever IP is xx-ed out. There are a few paths forward out of that situation:

- update away from using an IP address toward a hostname that *is* covered by the cert
- reissue the cert to include that IP in its SAN list
- update your [`Dialer`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer) to provide a [`tls.Config`](https://godoc.org/crypto/tls#Config) with `InsecureSkipVerify: true` and take your chances